# How to access home directories via server IP address

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, cpanel

I am trying to set my server up to access accounts such as:

```
192.169.200.88/~dirname
```

where `dirname` is the account's home directory.

I set the accounts up via WHM, and I can access the Cpanel. But home directories via IP address return the default Apache 404.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

It's not recommended to allow the user home directory to be directly accessed; if you want to allow per-user publishing then using a subdirectory such as `public_html` is more common.

Apache needs to be told about `~username` type syntax.  This is done with the `UserDir` directive.

eg

```
UserDir public_html
```

Now you also need to *permit* this access as well, so you would need a directive such as:

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

(Change the `Directory` line to match where user home directories are).

These two sets of commands (`UserDir` and the `Directory` setup) will allow users to create files such as `~/public_html/foo.html` and it will be accessible as `http://..../~username/foo.html`

Answer (score 0):

Apache, for a very good reason, is not made to descend into user's home directories, as this will create a security nightmare. I suggest you create a task scheduled with `cron` or your scheduling tool o f choice and `rsync` the files you are interested in the user's home directories to a location under the document_root of your apache web server, probably something like `/var/www/html`